# GWT refresh cyle in development mode

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, servlets

I am getting a serious problem with gwt. When I am first launching the server, I am viewing the page but later when refreshing the browser, I am getting a blank page. When I do view source, I see all the required tags such nocache.js and history frame but i get a blank screen

Comment: any exception on console ? or error message in browser error log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, When you refresh the page, you are  not on the home page. So you replace panels on onmodulLoad on the home page, but in other pages main panels is not generated and replaced in browser.

To check my theory. Please insert a System.out.println("isLoading"); start point of onModuleLoad. Be sure In initial case "isLoading" written to console. After try to refresh page. It it isn't written you must load your homepage whenever refreshed browser.

I hope, my solution is clear.

Comment: Ya, you are right, the problem was that a hiperlink was changing due to history token, u know sometimes when we got in complex issue we forget the simple one. lol